# Partition not working in my quicksort function

Tags: javascript, arrays, quicksort, partitioning

I've been working on this problem for a while and I can't get my partition function to work. I am increment the start value until it reaches a value less than the pivot and vice versa w/ my end-pointer. I swap values with my start and endpointer. Then I swap value with my start and pivot. Am I missing something?

```
function quickSort(arr, start, end) {
    if (start >= end) {
        return
    }


    let index = partition(arr, start, end)

    quickSort(arr, start, index - 1)
    quickSort(arr, index + 1, end)
    return arr
}

function partition(arr, start, end) {
    let pivotIndex = end 
    let pivotValue = arr[end]
    let endPointer = arr[end - 1] //end pointer start w/ value left of pivot

    while (start <= end) {
        if (arr[start] < pivotValue) {
            start++
        } else {
            swap(arr,start, endPointer)
        }
        if (arr[endPointer] > pivotValue) {
            endPointer--
        } else {
            swap(arr,start, endPointer)
        }
    }

    swap(arr,start, pivotIndex)
    return start


}

function swap(arr, a, b) {
    let temp = arr[a]
    arr[a] = arr[b]
    arr[b] = temp 
}

let arr = [0,5,2,1,6,3]
console.log(quickSort(arr, 0, arr.length - 1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The partition function appears to be a variation of Hoare. There are a few issues (endPointer should be end-1, not arr[end-1]; while (start < endPointer); if/else/swap if/else/swap should be while / while / swap / increment indexes again / ...) and by using the last value as pivot means the backwards scan will need to check if it has decremented below start. Normally Hoare relies on running into the pivot, so the pivot is chosen from the middle, or at least not from the first or last element. Here is an example of "classic" Hoare with partition code merged into the quicksort function:

```
function quicksort(a, lo, hi) {
  if(lo >= hi)
    return;
  var p = a[Math.floor(lo+(hi-lo)/2)];
  var i = lo - 1;
  var j = hi + 1;
  var t;
  while (true){
    while (a[++i] < p);
    while (a[--j] > p);
    if (i >= j)
      break;
    t = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = t;
  }
  quicksort(a, lo, j);
  quicksort(a, j+1, hi);
}
```

Since the code is using the last value for the pivot value, an alternative would be Lomuto partition scheme:

```
function quicksort(a, lo, hi) {
  if(lo >= hi)
    return;
  var p = a[hi];
  var i = lo;
  var j;
  var t;
  for(j = lo; j < hi; j++){
    if(a[j] < p){
      t = a[i];
      a[i] = a[j];
      a[j] = t;
      i++;
    }
  }
  t = a[i];
  a[i] = a[hi];
  a[hi] = t;
  quicksort(a, lo, i-1);
  quicksort(a, i+1, hi);
}
```